# How to change log4j setting during application run?

Tags: java, log4j

Is it possible to change log4j settings during application execution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch(java.lang.String)) to make log4j spawn a thread to periodically check your properties file for changes.

Alternatively, you can use JMX described in this post: [Change Logging Levels using JMX](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2008/06/change-logging-levels-using-jmx-howto.html)

Answer (score 3):

There ways of doing this by making your Log4j accessible through JMX and using a JMX console to control the filters, loggers, levels, appenders etc...

I have an example somewhere but I need to prune it a little to make it understandable.  Would you want this ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using:

- Windows 7
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.34
- log4j 1.2.17

and it is done **automatically** (no need to restart Tomcat) if you follow the next steps (let's suppose that you have already deployed the war file to %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps and you have launched **startup.bat**):

1. Go to %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\YourApp\WEB-INF\classes
2. Edit **log4j.properties** / **log4j.xml** and change the logger level

   E.g.:

   - log4j.properties:

     ```
     log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
     ```

     becomes

     ```
     log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
     ```
   - log4j.xml

     ```
     <root>
         <level value="INFO" />
         <appender-ref ref="console" />
         <appender-ref ref="file" />
     </root>
     ```

     becomes

     ```
     <root>
         <level value="DEBUG" />
         <appender-ref ref="console" />
         <appender-ref ref="file" />
     </root>
     ```

   If you have both files in the classes folder, the XML file will be considered (the .properties file will be ignored).
3. In 0-10 seconds you'll be able to see the following lines in **Tomcat console** and in %CATALINA_HOME%\logs\catalina.yourDate.log:

   > Nov 12, 2015 4:52:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
   >
   > INFO: Reloading Context with name [/YourApp] has started
   >
   > Nov 12, 2015 4:52:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
   >
   > INFO ...
   >
   > Nov 12, 2015 4:52:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
   >
   > INFO: Reloading Context with name [/YourApp] is completed
4. Use the application and see the new logging level (in console and/or in the logging files).